# Frozen list headers

Tags: list, custom

I have created a custom List in SharePoint 2010 and need to keep the headers frozen on top, so when scrolling down they don't move.

I only have access to out of the box.

Any solutions for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A no code solution would be to create a new 'DataSheet' view. Check it as the default view. Of course, that may not be the desired GUI presentation you were hoping for, but, you do get the static headers frozen to the top!